# Complicated Conditional Sum

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I want to ask a question on pandas, I think it would be good idea to explain the question by using small example.

I have

```
 Group     Price
 0         102
 0         103
 0         105
 1         106
 0         105
 0         106
 1         103
 0         105
```

I want

```
 Group     Price   Impact
 0         102     
 0         103
 0         105
 1         106     -5    (103 - 108)
 0         104
 0         108
 1         101     -3    (104-107)
 0         107
```

So, basically, I want to find the difference between previous (t-2) and following (t+2) second rows once my Group value equal 1 (t). For example, in first case, the value of impact equals to -5. This is simply because my group value is 1 in 4th row (t) and the code find the difference between second (t-2) and sixth (t+2) rows. I can it by using the following code:

```
 i = Data.loc[Data.Group.eq(1)].index.tolist()
 j = [(i-2,i+2) for i_ in i ]
 Data.loc[Data.Group.eq(1), 'impact'] = 
 [(Data.Price.iloc[b] - Data.Price.iloc[a]) for (a,b) in j]
```

However, if the condition is not satisfied in any rows, then I got the following error:

```
 IndexError: single positional indexer is out-of-bounds
```

For example, lets look at my have data again. As you can see, the value of Group equals 1 in 8th (t) row (Price = 101). Although, I have value in 6th row (t-2), I did not have 10th (t+2) row, because the data has 9 rows.

I want to develop code which use the closest value if data is not available. For example, as I said, the value of Group equals 1 in 8th (t) row. Normally, the code should find the difference between 6th and 10th row. However, since I do not have 10th row, I want to find the difference between 6th and 9th row.

I hope I could explain it.

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: Did your prices change in your output and input dataframes?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `ffill` and `bfill` after doing [`shift`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.shift.html) on the column 'Price' to get the missing values if out of bounds. First create a mask where the column 'Group' is 1. Then `shift` the value in 'Price' of 2 and -2, fill the `NaN` generated by the shifting operation and do the subtraction.

```
#create the mask
mask = df.Group == 1
# create the column Impact
df.loc[mask,'Impact'] = (df.Price.shift(2).bfill() - df.Price.shift(-2).ffill())[mask]
```

and you get

```
print (df)
   Group  Price  Impact
0      0    102     NaN
1      0    103     NaN
2      0    105     NaN
3      1    106    -5.0
4      0    104     NaN
5      0    108     NaN
6      1    101    -3.0
7      0    107     NaN
```

you can use `fillna` to replace all the Nan value in Impact by what you want

Thanks to [**@Scott Boston**](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6361531/scott-boston) who added a comment, you can use the method [`mask`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.mask.html) to do it in one line:

```
df['Impact'] = (df.Price.shift(2).bfill() - 
                      df.Price.shift(-2).ffill()).mask(df['Group'] != 1)
```

Comment: `df['Impact'] = (df.Price.shift(2).bfill() - df.Price.shift(-2).ffill()).mask(df['Group'] != 1)`

Comment: @ScottBoston thanks, I'm not using often this mask method